# How to get Firebase snapshots length?

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've created an app with Firebase but I've got a problem, which is that I

can't count the snapshot length in listview.builder.

```dart
StreamBuilder(
        stream:
            _firestore.collection('/posts/${widget.uid}/comments').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final data = snapshot.data.documents;

          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return SpinKitChasingDots(
              color: Colors.lightGreen,
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,//Here is the problem
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return PostComment(
                commentText: data[index]['commentText'],
                userImage: data[index]['userImage'],
                userName: data[index]['userName'],
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
```

When I run it gives me an error that it doesn't have actually a getter called length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to explicitly declare type in your `StreamBuilder`

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _firestore.collection('...').snapshots(),
```

https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems#runtime-errors

Comment: everything is going okay except displaying it as I've mentioned above

Comment: Can you confirm that you tried the answer and it didn't help?

Comment: I've not noticed your data type declaring and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

`snapshot.size`

Return size array result for request

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('/posts/${widget.uid}/comments').snapshots().length.toString();
```